# Experience of meditation

Tags: personal-practice, theravada

During meditation stop hearing sounds and going into darken space experience.After that  there is a gap between inspiration and expiration.short breaths.what's it ?

Comment: it's a sign you are entering, i.e., your mind is calm and gathered to a good condition. if you relax and keep it on, not striving for anything, maybe at certain point you will start to see dot of light in the *darken space* "in your mind's eyes" ~ (from Mahayana training)

Comment: "During meditation hearing sounds is stopped and experience goes into a dark space. After that there is a gap between inspiration and expiration.  Short breaths. What is it?"- Is that what is meant?

Answer (score 1):

In Zen, we'd call that Mu.  It's a state of blankness or voidness.  The aim of emptiness meditation is to widen that gap.  Eventually it will pervade your entire consciousness, the in breath, the out breath, and even your total body will be awash in that emptiness.  Once you've done that, then the real practice begins!

Comment: When the real practice begins, one should know the arising and passing away of sense objects in that emptiness?

Comment: Nope, just look into the emptiness.  As you come out of that emptiness, then you can apply it back to the world of form.